# Need help in creating ledger from table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Everyone..I am just stuck with scenario that i have two table like below. First Table is tblCharge and second one is tblPayment

```
chargeId   Plan   TotalAmount
 1         A        400
 2         B        200
 3         C        300 


PaymentId  ChargeId  PayAmount
 1            1       100
 2            1       50
 3            1       70
 4            1       120
 5            1       10
 6            2       50
 7            2       70
```

I want output like below by joining both above table.Total amount should be subtracted from the pay amount in every row.

```
Plan    Amount  Pay
A       400     100
A       300     50
A       250     70
A       180     120
A       60      10
```

Comment: Have you written any code yourself yet? Can you share your code?

Comment: Select tblCharge.strCharge [Plan]
,tblCharge.fltChargeAmount-tblPaymentDetail.fltAmount [Amount]
,tblPaymentDetail.fltAmount [Amount Pay]

 from tblCharge

inner join tblPayment on tblCharge.ChargeId=tblPaymentDetail.intChargeId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- sample table
declare @tblCharge table
(
    ChargeId    int,
    [Plan]      char,
    TotalAmount int
)

declare @tblPayment table
(
    PaymentId   int,
    ChargeId    int,
    PayAmount   int
)

-- sample data
insert into @tblCharge select 1, 'A', 400
insert into @tblCharge select 2, 'B', 200
insert into @tblCharge select 3, 'C', 300

insert into @tblPayment select 1, 1, 100
insert into @tblPayment select 2, 1, 50
insert into @tblPayment select 3, 1, 70
insert into @tblPayment select 4, 1, 120
insert into @tblPayment select 5, 1, 10
insert into @tblPayment select 6, 2, 50
insert into @tblPayment select 7, 2, 70

-- the query
select  c.[Plan], 
    c.TotalAmount - isnull(a.Amt, 0) as Amount,
    p.PayAmount as Pay
from    @tblCharge c
    inner join @tblPayment p    on  c.ChargeId  = p.ChargeId
    cross apply
    (
        select  sum(x.PayAmount) as Amt
        from    @tblPayment x
        where   x.ChargeId  = c.ChargeId
        and x.PaymentId < p.PaymentId
    ) a
order by c.ChargeId, p.PaymentId
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUM OVER()`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4009/1/0)

```
SELECT
    c.ChargeId,
    Amount = TotalAmount 
                - SUM(PayAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY c.[Plan] ORDER BY p.PaymentId) 
                + PayAmount,
    p.PayAmount
FROM tblCharge c
INNER JOIN tblPayment p
    ON p.ChargeId = c.ChargeId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get your required result

```
    select chargeid,
    totalamount-isnull(lag(amount) over(partition by chargeid order by chargeid),0) as amount,
    payamount as pay
from (
    select t2.chargeid
        ,t1.totalamount
        ,sum(t2.payamount) over (
            partition by t2.chargeid order by t2.paymentid
            ) as amount,
            t2.payamount
    from tblCharge t1
    join tblpayment t2 on t1.chargeid = t2.chargeid
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this simple query will solve your problem.

```
SELECT C.[Plan],C.TotalAmount - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(PT.PayAmount) FROM tblPayment PT 
    WHERE PT.ChargeId = C.ChargeId AND PT.PaymentId < P.PaymentId),0) Amount,P.PayAmount Pay
FROM    tblCharge C
INNER JOIN tblPayment P ON P.ChargeId = C.ChargeId
```